# Awkward shell outputs for launching many nodes using a configuration file

Tags: ros2, ros2-launch, foxy

I'm launching multiple nodes of *unknown* count using a configuration file that I provide to the backend launcher. So far, I *appear* to have no issues accomplishing this.
However, calling `ros2 node list` and `ros2 topic list` afterwards makes it seem one of my nodes to "vanish". The node still runs on my screen, and manages to publish its associated topics. Should I be worried?

---

I'll post a screenshot, and the minimal working example constructed in Foxy using the `talker.py` example from the tutorials.
Let's begin with the file tree, which is quite straightforward:

```
└── dummy
    ├── config
    │   └── talker.yml
    ├── dummy
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   └── talker.py
    ├── launch
    │   ├── talker.launch.xml
    │   ├── talker_mux.launch.py
    │   └── talker_start.launch.xml
    ├── package.xml
    ├── resource
    ├── setup.cfg
    ├── setup.py
    └── test
7 directories, 15 files 
(I suppressed __pycache__, etc. folder contents)
```

Here, you can see 3 different launch files and a YAML file.
One little modification I've made to `talker.py` is to print its namespace rather than "Hello World".
`talker.yml`: just namespace and count

```yaml
ns: "dummy"
count: 6
```

`talker.launch.xml`: simple xml launchfile for the node only

```xml
<launch>
    <node pkg="dummy" exec="talker" name="talker"/>
</launch>
```

`talker_start.launch.xml`: calls the python backend launcher

```xml
<launch>
    <!-- Run the python launcher for multi-robot setups -->
    <include file="$(find-pkg-share dummy)/launch/talker_mux.launch.py"/>
</launch>
```

`talker_mux.launch.py`: Calls multiple `talker` nodes by assigning variable namespaces to launchfiles in a for-loop. Most involved part of this launch sequence.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import yaml
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import IncludeLaunchDescription, GroupAction
from launch_xml.launch_description_sources import XMLLaunchDescriptionSource
from launch_ros.actions import PushRosNamespace

def generate_launch_description():
    launch_actions = []
    pkg_name = 'dummy'
    launch_file = 'talker.launch.xml'
    
    # sniff parameters from YAML to get namespace and robot count (needs to be installed, modify setup.py or CMakeLists.txt accordingly)
    # path: <workspace_path>/install/<pkg_name>/share/<pkg_name>/config/talker.yml 
    dir = get_package_share_directory(pkg_name) + '/config/talker.yml'
    with open(dir, 'r') as file:
        params = yaml.safe_load(file)
    
    robot_ns = params['ns']
    robot_count = params['count']
    print(f"Initializing multi-robot launch...\nNamespace:{robot_ns}, #: {robot_count}")

    # ref: <https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Launch-file-different-formats.html>
    for i in range(robot_count):
        launch_actions.append(
            GroupAction(
                actions=[
                    PushRosNamespace(f'{robot_ns}{i}'),
                    IncludeLaunchDescription(
                        XMLLaunchDescriptionSource(                    
                            os.path.join(get_package_share_directory(pkg_name),f'launch/{launch_file}')
                        )
                    ),
                ]
            )
        )

    return LaunchDescription(launch_actions)
```

Here's what happens when you call `talker_start.launch.xml`. Somehow `/dummy2/talker` is missing, but it still publishes its own topic.
[image: Where did dummy2 go?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the specifics of this problem, but after upgrading to Humble I seem to not have this issue anymore.
I'll mark this as answered.